No ObservableObject of type T found
In the code below I'm getting the error below but I don't understand why.

No ObservableObject of type Plotter found. A
View.environmentObject(_:) for Plotter may be missing as an ancestor
of this view."

The @StateObject is inserted into the parent ContentView, added to the environment of the DetailView and pulled out via @EnvironmentObject in the DetailView itself.
From everything I've read, that should be the correct way to do it.  What am I missing?
import SwiftUI

class Plotter : ObservableObject
{
    @Published var fileStem : String = "bobo"
}

struct ContentView : View
{
    @StateObject var mPlotter = Plotter()

    var body: some View
    {
        DetailView()
            .environmentObject(mPlotter)
    }
}

struct DetailView : View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var mPlotter : Plotter
    
    init()
    {
        let fs = mPlotter.fileStem + ".txt"
        print("fileStem: \(fs)")
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Text("This is text")
    }
}


It isn’t available on init. Use on appear

At the time of init, the @EnvironmentObject isn't available, as you can see:
DetailView() //<- this will call the init() function

However, .environmentObject is a function that will be applied AFTER DetailView was initialized.
So, you can try this approach, using mPlotter directly in the Text.
struct DetailView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mPlotter: Plotter
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is \(mPlotter.fileStem).txt")
    }
}

